# Number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following terms are found by alternately adding 4 and 6 to the previous term.
The first six terms are  13, 17, 23, 27, 33, 37. 
(a)  Find the 80th term. 
(b) The nth term is 203.  Find n.

Note: This is GCSE level question with no missing or mistakes. The answers are, (a) 407. and (b) n=39. but I dont understand how to write the detailed solution. Pls help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Your edit did add some useful information, but you have more to do to reopen this question. What do you mean by "how to write the detailed solution": do you mean how to get the answer or how to write it up for some supervisor? Also, Brian M. Scott gave you an excellent hint. Have you followed that up? How far did you get with that? You still have not shown any work of your own!

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Alternate terms are $4+6=10$ units apart. Thus, you have an arithmetic sequence $13,23,33,43,\ldots$ with constant difference $10$ interlaced with another, $17,27,37,47,\ldots\;$. The first, third, fifth, etc. terms are in the first of these; the second, fourth, sixth, etc. are in the second.

- Which one contains the $80$-th term? Which term in that subsequence is it? (For instance, $33$ is the third term of the first subsequence, and $37$ is the third term of the second subsequence.)
- Which subsequence contains $203$? Which term in that subsequence is it? Once you have that, you can figure out which term in the original mixed sequence it is.

The point of splitting the sequence in two in this way is that each of the subsequences is arithmetic, and you’ve already learned how to work with arithmetic sequences.

Comment: Thank you Brian. After reading your hint, I was able to solve the question. Thank you again.

Comment: @Asim: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Set $(a_n)$ such sequence. Remark that $a_1=13,$ $a_2=17,$ $a_3=23,$ $a_4=33,$ $a_5=37$ then if $k= 1 \mod{2}$ then $a_k=3+10\times k,$ if $k=0 \mod{2}$ then $a_k=7+10\times (k-1).$